# My Emulator is Not running. Even nothing is showing in the Logcat. It shows "No Connected device" and "No Debuggable pro"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have not connected any physical devices with the system.  When I am selecting any virtual device, it not takes.

Logcat shows `"No Connected Device"` and `"No Debbugable process"`. I tried to end the `adb.exe` through Task Manager, but it starts again and again.

Earlier it was working fine. But don't know what happens it right now. I searched lot but not able to solve this.

```
6:00 PM * daemon started successfully
6:00 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
6:00 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Another emulator instance is 
    running. Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag.
6:00 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
6:00 PM Gradle build finished in 1 s 783 ms
```

I am new in Android so please tell me step by step

Comment: **CTRL+SHIFT+ESC** close the process which seems to you like an emulator, restart the emulator.

Comment: I already did this many times. But it throws an Connection error..

Comment: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

6:17 PM Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might not be listening to the error being thrown by the emulator but in any case, go to the folder where the AVD image is stored.

On windows, its `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\AVDname.avd` and delete any .lock file in this folder. the emulator should restart properly.

Comment: Bro , thank you very much. Now my virtual device is running.

Comment: But Still in Logcat , "No Debuggable Pro" is showing. As a result , my application is not running. I checked my Setting, its check on the Logcat.

Comment: "No Debuggable Pro" bug is also solve, after Cleaning the project. Thanks