# Emulator doesn't start (Connecting to the emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to launch an emulator long time ago, but neither I could launch it nor I found any information about how to fix this problem. When I start an emulator, I get this window below:

[image]

Emulator's details:

```
Name: Pixel_2_API_30
CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\Me\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_30.avd
Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 30)
Skin: pixel_2
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_2
hw.lcd.width: 1080
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 30
tag.id: google_apis_playstore
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 API 30
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: true
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 2
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1920
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_2_API_30
hw.lcd.density: 420
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a6
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google Play
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

SDK Tools I've got:

[image]

PC specs:

NVIDIA GeForce GT 630

[image]

I tried wiping the data, relaunching the emulator, creating new one - nothing helped. I hope someone could help me to launch this emulator. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573554/my-emulator-is-not-running-even-nothing-is-showing-in-the-logcat-it-shows-no

Comment: It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What Operating System are you using (Windows / Linux / MacOS) ?

Comment: @UserRebo Windows

Comment: I have a similar issue with Android Emulator on Linux:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187448654 . Would be interesting to see the idea.log
Does it work with disabling Setting "Launch in a tool window"?

Comment: I had the same problem and wiping the data resolved the issue

Answer (score 77):

Had the same issue on a Mac and this worked for me: go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator -> Uncheck “Launch in a tool window”. After that try to launch the emulator again.

Comment: Phew. Fixed the issue for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of a tool window, if it doesn't work at all, lol

Comment: This problem showed up just after upgrading Android Studio for me. This was the correct solution

Comment: If anyone's wondering, on windows you go to "File > Settings" rather than "Preferences"

Comment: The issue started appearing after upgrading Android Studio and using pre-existing emulator. This made the emulator show up but wasn't booting. I also had to recreate the emulator.

Comment: Android Studio appears to be worse than Visual Studio and THAT'S a pile of garbage

Comment: And..that worked. You saved me some time!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 20 and the following steps work for me: file -> settings -> tools -> Emulator -> uncheck Launch in a tool window. Then launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fGOO.png)

Check the Android Emulator option in SDK Tools to install

Answer (score 0):

Moving the emulator out of the tool window didn't work for me; best solution for me (running on a Mac) was Force Quit the process in Activity Monitor.

Easy to find the process because it was using the most CPU, but mine is called `qemu-system-x86_64`

Answer (score -2):

there are many reasons for an emulator to get into a loop.

1. Try to reinstall it
2. Install a new device and Android version
3. If you have an android device, unlock developer option and enable USB debugging. Then connect your Android device to your computer. Then run your program on your physical device.(Best option)

//Check whether V-Sync is enabled in your computer's BIOS. If not get it enabled.

Comment: None of these solved problem. I'm looking forward to launch it on emulator, not real device.

Comment: What is your system configuration @cjacky475?

Comment: Does your IDE show "Waiting to device come online" at bottom?

Comment: What would you need to know of my system's config? No, to my knowledge, that message doesn't show at the bottom.

Comment: Knowing your system config makes me be more specific abt ur problem.

Comment: Does your gradle sync?

Comment: I updated my post with specs. Is it enough? Yes, my gradle sync. I can launch my project on real device.

Comment: May be your emulator is taking its time to boot, In my case it would take (3-8)min to boot for the first time, for intel processors(i3,i5).

Comment: I've waited a bit longer and received: `Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.`